# ReactJS: Strategy to replace webpack environment variable at deploy time

Tags: reactjs, webpack, deployment

Currently when building our react application, we are using Webpack like so

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    REACT_APP_BASE_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL),
    ... 20 more lines,
```

So, these parameters are supplied at build time, the react application is built to static file and then served with an nginx that we have full control

Through out the application, we use `process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL` and those 20 more `process.env.x` variables.

Previously, for each runtime environment, we need to build the application again and provide respective parameters at build time. Now we are trying to build once and insert these parameters at **deploy** time.

My question is what is the most feasible way to provide those variable at deploy time with the least impact/change to our current source code?

Answer (score 0):

make different .env file like .env.production, .env.qa and user it in script of package.js [enter link description here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#customizing-environment-variables-for-arbitrary-build-environments)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not use create-react-app which I thnk that's what they ultimately relied on to have different environments in the URL you referenced :(